# Multiple useState in useEffect, order of execution

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What happens after the render due to the first useState? Does execution begin immediately at the second useState?

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    const [var1, setVar1] = useState();
    const [var2, setVar2] = useState();
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        if (var1) {
          setVar2('abc')
          setVar1('zyx')
        }
    }, [var1]);
```

Comment: you will re-render your component twice

Comment: I think this question is not quite clear, or is my EL reading bad?. For example, *What happens after the render* => `componentDidMount` or the equivalent `useEffect`. But *What happens after the render due to the first useState*, I can't understand.

Comment: *Does execution begin immediately at the second useState*, by `useState` did you mean `setVar1`?

Comment: If you want the exact understanding of what Hooks does under the hood, step by step order of execution, I think you should read some articles and code several projects, you'll learn it along the way. If what you want is how `useState` does under the hood, as I remember Dan Abramov said that it's just a chunk of memory, kinda an array, you should google to take further. If what you want is the order of execution inside the `useEffect`, I can tell you.

Comment: I understand that it renders twice.  I wanted to know about the execution in the useEffect: after the setVar2 and its associated render, does execution begin directly at the setVar1 statement?

Comment: That's not how it works. It doesn't call `setVar2` then re-render, and then pick back up at `setVar1`. It executes the whole function in the effect, then re-renders with both changes made. Setting state is async, but react knows to wait to re-render until the updates are finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly:

`useEffect`'s runs after the render. So the execution would be:

- useState 1
- useState 2
- return
- useEffect (only run if your dependencies change)
- re-render

Inside your `useEffect`, the `setVar2` setter will be called before the first. But remember that setting state is async, so the first executed does not mean the first to finish.

To answer the more specific question about the order of execution inside an effect consider the console logs in your example:

```js
const TestEffect= (props) => {
  const [test, setTest] = React.useState();
  const [test2, setTest2] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect was called')

    setTest2('test2');
    console.log('set test 2 called')

    setTest('test');
    console.log('set test 1 called')
  }, [test])

  console.log('render')
  return <div>Test</div>;
}

// Output:

// render
// effect was called
// set test 2 called
// set test 1 called
// render
// effect was called
// set test 2 called
// set test 1 called
// render
```